# Flask url_for between two files BuildError

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I have a flask app that is a login system.

I am trying to send the full name which is captured in `auth.py` to `main.py`. To do so, I'm doing this:

```
# auth.py
@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    fname = request.form.get('fullname')
    return redirect(url_for('main.profile', fullname=fname))

# main.py
from flask_login import login_required, current_user

@main.route('/profile/<fullname>')
@login_required
def profile(fullname):
    return render_template('profile.html', name=fullname)
```

However, when it redirects, I get this error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'main.profile'. Did you forget to specify values ['fullname']?
```

Does anyone know why? Am I not linking my url_for path correctly?

Comment: Is the form actually returning a value? Try to debug and check `fname`.

Comment: So I got rid of the variable  `fullname` in `profile` and printed fname before redirecting and it worked. so it must be a problem with either `return redirect(url_for('main.profile', fullname=fname))` or the `profile route` @eagr

Answer (score 0):

You spelled fullname differently. In some other code you try to access field 'full name'.

Comment: That was a typo in the question, fixed now.